# Github Change author / email of squash and merge

Tags: git, github

Unfortunately GitHub used a wrong email when I used the "Squash and Merge" function for merging a branch into another.

The commits / pushes from my working station were done with email A (correct working mail) but when using the online function of squash and merge on the GitHub web UI changed all code as it was done by email B (primary mail).

Is there a way I can change the author back to email A?

Comment: Wrong site, should be https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok, i will post it there and delete it here